# How to convert the equation into this two forms?

Tags: equation-solving

The equation is:

```
x0^2/a^2 - y0^2/b^2 == 1
```

How to convert to this two forms:

```
b^2 x0^2 - a^2 y0^2 -> a^2 b^2
```

and

```
a^2 b^2 ->b^2 x0^2 - a^2 y0^2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Assuming[a != 0 && b != 0, 
  Together[eq] // MultiplySides[#, a^2 b^2] &] /. Equal -> Rule
```

$b^2 \text{x0}^2-a^2 \text{y0}^2\to a^2 b^2$

---

```
(Assuming[a != 0 && b != 0, 
    Together[eq] // MultiplySides[#, a^2 b^2] &] // Reverse) /. 
 Equal :> Rule
```

$a^2 b^2\to b^2 \text{x0}^2-a^2 \text{y0}^2$